# figure numbering with endfloat and appendix

Tags: floats, lyx, appendices, endfloat

I have a document which has figures and tables.  The document also has an appendix.  The tables seem to be labeled normally (1...N), however the figures seem to be labeled A.1, A.2, etc.  I would like my figures labeled 1...N as well.  How does one do this?  I am using LyX as my editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed this by doing:

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{figure}{section}
```

This basically makes counters not label things as Section.## but just as ##.