# Change figure numbering for appendix - when using endfloat and double spacing

Tags: floats, numbering, appendices, endfloat

I am trying to change the format of the figure numbering for the appendix of my document.  I also want to use double spacing in the document and to use the `endfloat` package.  For the basic case of just changing the format of figure numbering, I can follow along perfectly with the example in this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/85778/49603) to this question: [Change figure numbering for appendix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85776/change-figure-numbering-for-appendix).  But, when I try to add *both* the `endfloat` package and double spacing, the solution falls apart.  What is curious is that either on their own works fine.  Below is a minimal working example, based on the answer cited above.  If I make *either* of the below two modifications, the example successfully changes the format of the figure numbering, but lacking that, it does not:

1. Comment out `\begin{spacing}{2}` and `\end{spacing}`
2. Comment out `\usepackage[notablist,nofiglist,nomarkers]{endfloat}` and `\processdelayedfloats`

.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[notablist,nofiglist,nomarkers]{endfloat}  %% places all figures and tables at the end.
\usepackage{setspace} % Allows for double spacing
\begin{document}

\begin{spacing}{2}

Body Text.

\begin{figure}
\centering\rule{1cm}{1cm}
\caption{This is a figure}
\end{figure}

\processdelayedfloats  

\appendix
\renewcommand\thefigure{\thesection.\arabic{figure}}    
\section{Appendix}
\setcounter{figure}{0}

Appendix Text.

\begin{figure}
\centering\rule{1cm}{1cm}
\caption{This is a figure in appendix A}
\end{figure}

\end{spacing}
\end{document}
```

I also tried the solution suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/104264/figure-numbering-with-endfloat-and-appendix).  I don't believe it worked, but the question was not set up with any kind of reproducible example, nor did the answer make very clear how / where it was to be implemented, so it is possible there is a mechanism using those techniques that is eluding me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nesting introduced by `\begin{spacing}...\end{spacing}` prevents `\thefigure` working as desired -- the change done with `\renewcommand` is only local, but not working outside, i.e. during the writing process with `endfloat` at the end of the document, i.e. beyond the `spacing` environment. The solution is to use `\gdef\thefigure{...}` to enable the change globally.

This will change any `\thefigure` of course, but since this is to be done in the appendix, this should not cause troubles, in my opinion.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[notablist,nofiglist,nomarkers]{endfloat}  %% places all figures and tables at the end.
\usepackage{setspace} % Allows for double spacing
\begin{document}

\begin{spacing}{2}

Body Text.

\begin{figure}
\centering\rule{1cm}{1cm}
\caption{This is a figure}
\end{figure}

\processdelayedfloats  

\appendix
\gdef\thefigure{\thesection.\arabic{figure}}    
\section{Appendix}
\setcounter{figure}{0}

Appendix Text.

\begin{figure}
\centering\rule{1cm}{1cm}
\caption{This is a figure in appendix A}
\end{figure}

\end{spacing}
\end{document}
```

[image]